# Gmail breaks the formatting of my HTML email?

Tags: html, email, gmail

I am attempting to create an HTML newsletter to send out.  I have created the newsletter in Microsoft Publisher and exported it to HTML.  I then open the HTML file and select all and paste it into a Gmail draft.  In the preview, the newsletter looks great but when I send it to myself and receive it, Gmail completely breaks the formatting and pushes all the text below the image.  When I tested this with my AOL email, the formatting was fine and the text was on top of the image where its supposed to be.  I even tried using Mailchimp to code the newsletter and it also appeared to be fine but when I sent it to all my emails, Gmail was the only one that broke the format.  The email looks perfect on AOL and even on my iPhone Mail App which is connected to my Gmail.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please post the relevent HTML and possibly screenshots of what's going wrong on Gmail? That will help us debug what's going wrong.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel [This](http://i.imgur.com/XnLo9Kw.png) is how Gmail formats the email, which is incorrect.  [This](http://i.imgur.com/SgLiYdf.png) is how AOL formats the email which is the right way.  I am unsure what part of my HTML code is causing this, if it is my code itself.

Comment: Alright, it looks like the larger font or some exterior scaling is making the box too big, causing it to be pushed down. Consider having a `max-width` for it?

Comment: If you use the desktop client of gmail, you can use your browser's inspector to debug it too.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel Would you like to see the HTML of the text box?

Comment: Sure, but without the full context, + being able to sim it in Gmail, I'm not sure if I'll find the problem.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel [Here](http://pastebin.com/BaaGfpUF) is the code for the table.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the columns are being lined up wrong, but from the code you have sent this is probably the least of your worries. Creating a html email in Microsoft Publisher is a bad idea. You might be better using something like mailchimp's free builder and copying the html out of that (or even just sending from there)